# Refreshing php output in div using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I have gathered this code, Is there a way I can make the code shorter and support multiple different `divs:php` files? Using AJAX maybe, I have looked around and haven't found anything useful.

```
$(function() {
    function reloadTable() {
        $.get( "table1.php", function( data ) {
            $( "#RealTime" ).html( data );
        });
    }
    reload = setInterval(reloadTable, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You can use jquery load http://api.jquery.com/load/ function refresh div.

Comment: be specific to your requirements

Comment: Just use additional `$.get` calls and change the php file and div id?

Comment: ccKep can i get an example?

Comment: Literally duplicate lines 3-5 (including) and change `table1.php` and `#RealTime` to your 2nd source and 2nd div's name. I won't provide this an an answer and it'd be too poor to read in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create it

```
<script>
 function loadData()
 {
      $("#divtest").load("divdata.php");
 }
 </script>
```

Then

```
<body onload="setInterval('loadData()', 500);">
```